# How to perform an operation on every item in java.util.Set using stream/ifPresent?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, option-type

I have a question about streams/optionals.

I want to perform an delete operation on a set of items fetched in a query:

```
providerRepository.findByUserId(user.getId()).ifPresent(providerRepository::delete);
```

But my IDE says:

```
Incompatible types: Set<AuthenticationProvider> is not convertible to AuthenticationProvider
```

How do I perform an operation on every single item in a collection?

Comment: Where does the collection fit in? Please provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you show the `providerRepository::delete` method definition ?

Comment: Show the definition of the method *findByUserId*. Especially interesting is what it returns: single object, list, set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate in your `ifPresent`:

```
providerRepository.findByUserId(user.getId())
    .ifPresent(set -> set.forEach(providerRepository::delete));
```

Or, get an empty set in the case of nothing being found, and then iterate the set:

```
providerRepository.findByUserId(user.getId())
    .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
    .forEach(providerRepository::delete);
```